# Solving $Ae^x=Bx$ analytically, where $A$ and $B$ are constants?

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving, exponential-function

This equation mixes both exponential terms and linear terms, something which I do not know how to deal with. Any pointers?

Comment: Newton Raphson Method.

Comment: Is there no closed-form solution whatsoever?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @user151634 depends on what you call closed form. If you are willing to define new functions, it is closed form.

Answer (score 0):

$$-xe^{-x}=-\dfrac{A}{B}$$
Thus,
$$x=-W\left(-\dfrac{A}{B}\right)$$
Where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).